# Unit test Observable.interval

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs

I have a function that polls an api until the desired result is returned or until a timeout period has been reached.

```
// sample poll, filter and timeout
   pollStatus = (): Observable<string> => {
            return Observable.interval(1000)
              .mergeMap(() => this.getStatus(); // this makes a http call to a status api
              .map((response) => response.json())
              .filter((responseData) => responseData.status !== 'PENDING')
              .take(1)
              .map((response) => response.status)
              .catch((error) => Observable.throw({message: 'FAILED'}))
              .timeout(5000);
          };
```

In my test I want to execute the the pollStatus() function and ensure that the getStatus() function has been called the correct number of times etc but I can't event to get it to call it once. What is the best way to test Observable.interval and how can I force a new interval to occur?

Comment: if you are inside of Angular you need to use fakeAsync and tick utilities of Angular.

Comment: Thanks Julia. I ended up going with the fakeAsync approach

Answer (score 0):

For testing Rx code you will need to pass a [`VirtualTimeScheduler`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/testing/testscheduler.md) so you can advance the time in your tests. You can use the compat package [`@kwonoj/rxjs-testscheduler-compat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kwonoj/rxjs-testscheduler-compat) so you can write tests in RxJs5 as you would have written them in RxJs4:

```
import { TestScheduler, next, complete } from '@kwonoj/rxjs-testscheduler-compat';

const scheduler = new TestScheduler();
const results = scheduler.startScheduler(
  () => pollStatus(scheduler),
  { created: 100, subscribed: 200, unsubscribed: 4000 }
);
```

You will need to pass the scheduler to the time-based operators so they will schedule their work not on the default scheduler but the one you have supplied:

```
pollStatus = (scheduler?:Rx.Scheduler): Observable<string> => {
  return Observable.interval(1000, scheduler)
    .mergeMap(() => this.getStatus(); // this makes a http call to a status api
    .map((response) => response.json())
    .filter((responseData) => responseData.status !== 'PENDING')
    .take(1)
    .map((response) => response.status)
    .catch((error) => Observable.throw({message: 'FAILED'}))
    .timeout(5000, scheduler);
};
```

You are then able to observe that your code runs in virtual time in your tests and you can then start creating mocks for `this.getStatus()` to have it be slower then 5000 ms so your `timeout()` hits etc.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will have a go at this and report back. I'm assuming there is no way I can avoid passing in the scheduler into the function as it is only used for testing?

Comment: you can try to inject the scheduler into the rx functions using things like https://github.com/tchock/RxJS-TestScheduler-Injector

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Mark. I had trouble getting the tests to work with Scheduler to work with the tests. I ended up just using fakeAsync() and tick()